# Laravel inserting by relationship to composite key table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6, composite-primary-key

I have these tables currently:

**User table**

```
id (primary key), name, email
```

**User Model**

```
protected $fillable = ['name', 'email'];
protected $visible = ['id','name','email'];
//Relationship
public function customAttributes()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\UserAttribute');
}
```

**UserAttribute Table**

```
user_id, attribute_id, value //user_id and attribute_id is a composite key, both foreignkeys acting as primary keys establishing an unique combination
```

**UserAttribute Model**

```
protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'attribute_id','value'];
protected $visible = ['user_id', 'attribute_id','value'];
```

I'll use the following example to explain the issue:

```
$user = $this->user->create(['name' => 'admin', 'email' => 'admin@admin.com']);
//This works
$user->customAttributes()->save(new \App\Models\UserAttribute(['user_id' => $user->id, 'attribute_id' => 1, 'value' => 'Just a custom1']));
//This does not work 
$user->customAttributes()->create([new \App\Models\UserAttribute(['user_id' => $user->id, 'attribute_id' => 1, 'value' => 'Just a custom1'])]);
```

I could just repeat the `save` for every custom that I want since it works, but I'm trying to figure out why `create` doesn't work.

The error I'm getting when I use create is (and yes, I've checked the record exists in the table that isn't listed here):

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`testdatabase`.`user_attributes`, 
CONSTRAINT `user_attributes_attribute_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_id`) REFERENCES `attributes` (`id`))
```

This is the query it's trying to execute:

```
insert into `user_attributes` (`user_id`) values (1)
```

I'm just curious at why this doesn't work with `create`, I'm not sure if it's something related to this specific scenario (create to a composite key table by relationship). It's somewhat ignoring the `value` and `attribute_id` field in the query that is executing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$user->customAttributes()->create(['user_id' => $user->id, 'attribute_id' => 1, 'value' => 'Just a custom1']);
```

Comment: I actually have no idea why I didn't try without the new model, thanks.

Comment: if you can, take a look at the edit of my post,a new situation has emerged

Comment: @abr use createMany() in place of create()

Answer (score 1):

`customAttributes()` already returns you instance of UserAttribute model, you don't need to enject that dependency when you use `create()` method via that relation

your query should be like below;

```
$user->customAttributes()->insert([
   [
   'user_id' => $user->id,
   'attribute_id' => 1,
   'value' => 'Just a custom1'
   ],
   [
   'user_id' => $user->id,
   'attribute_id' => 2,
   'value' => 'Just a custom2'
   ],
]);
```

Comment: if you can, take a look at the edit of my post,a new situation has emerged

Comment: if you want to create mass record you need to use `insert()` method instead `create()` I edited my question